# How to include SQL select statement in dsbulk unload command

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I have a huge orderhistory table in cassandra having data from 2013, But I want only last 12 months of orderhistory data to be unloaded, I use the below command to do it which unloads all the data starting from 2013 and stores in the path `data/json/customer_data/orderhistory/data`. How do I modify the below statement such that each time I run this it should select only last 12months of data?

```bash
dsbulk unload -k customer_data -t crawlsiteidentifiedpages -h '172.xx.xx.xxx' \
  -c json -url data/json/customer_data/orderhistory/data
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove options `-k` and `-t`, and instead use the `-query` option as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/schemaOptions.html), like:

```
dsbulk unload -query 'select * from ks.table where <your condition>'
```

To make sure that unload is parallelized, make sure that your condition includes part like `and token(pkcol) > :start and token(pkcol) <= :end` where `pkcol` is the name of the partition column (if you have multiple partition columns, specify them comma-separated).

Comment: Hello @Alex , I tried but not working: dsbulk unload -query "select * from ks.table where token(url) > :start and token(url) <= :end and lastupdatetime >= toTimestamp('2021-06-01 08:21:55.717') ALLOW FILTERING" -h '172.xx.xx.xxx, 172.xx.xx.xxx' -c json -url data/json/ks/table/data

Comment: what doesn't work? please update your post with error

Comment: I get this error: failed: Unknown CQL3 function toTimestamp called.
I am Unable to figure out the exact syntax to fetch last 12 months, Help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-t crawlsiteidentifiedpages` you should use `-query` and provide the SELECT query, e.g.:

```
-query "SELECT * FROM crawlsiteidentifiedpages WHERE token(pk) > :start and token(pk) <= :end and date > maxTimeuuid('2021-06-21+0000') ALLOW FILTERING"
```

A few remarks:

1. I assume your table has one partition key column `pk` and one clustering column `date` of type `timeuuid` – please adjust the actual query accordingly.
2. The WHERE restriction `token(pk) > :start and token(pk) <= :end` allows DSBulk to parallelize the operation and improves performance.
3. The WHERE restriction `date > maxTimeuuid('2021-06-21+0000')` is where the magic happens and allows you to select only the last 12 months of data.
4. Unfortunately, you also need to add `ALLOW FILTERING` to this type of query, otherwise Cassandra will reject the query.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I need another help, Each time when I run this command, It creates 2 json files however small or big the data is. My question is, How do I have control over the number of files?Suppose I want to have 5 files instead of 2?

Comment: You need to add -maxConcurrentFiles 1